# Data cannot be injected into Fragment using Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have data created in ApplicationModule which I want to inject into a fragment and I get:

`Data cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method`

Here is my sample code:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    BaseApplication baseApplication();
    Data data();

}
```

ApplicationModule:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final BaseApplication mApplication;

    public ApplicationModule(BaseApplication application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    BaseApplication provideBaseApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Data provideData() {
        return new Data("sample data");
    }

}
```

Next comes activity component:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,
        modules = {
                ActivityModule.class
        }
)
public interface ActivityComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);

}
```

And activity module:

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {

    private AppCompatActivity mActivity;

    public ActivityModule(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

}
```

Next is fragment component:

```
@PerFragment
@Component(dependencies = ActivityComponent.class, modules = FragmentModule.class)
public interface FragmentComponent {

    void inject(MainFragment fragment);

}
```

And finally fragment module:

```
@Module
public class FragmentModule {

    private final MainFragment mFragment;

    public FragmentModule(MainFragment fragment) {
        this.mFragment = fragment;
    }

}
```

I inject Data into Fragment and get the error.

Now I don't understand why I am getting the error. Please help me with this as I have looked into sample code on the internet and I don't see what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Try adding ``Data getData();`` to your ``ActivityComponent`` and try again. Given the dependencies you have between components I think Dagger is unable to know that the ``ApplicationComponent`` is the one binding the provider for ``Data``.

Comment: @Fred it fixes the issue. But I want ApplicationComponent to provide Data. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: well, the application module is the actual thing that provides the dependency. The components just bind it. So if you leave the provides in the application module and just add ``Data getData();`` to both components - application and activity - you should be fine to get it from both places.